# Add textbox then get the input [PHP]

Tags: php, html, post

I have this table that lets the user add a textbox. I'm trying to figure out, what code to write if the user, clicks the add, then a textbox will appear and if they input something in that textbox, I need to get the value of that textbox. How will I do that by using the `$_POST['']`?

```
<TABLE id="tbl1" border="1">
     <TR>
         <th width="5%"></th>
         <TH>Principal Name</TH>
         <TH>Principal Titles</TH>
      </TR>
      <TR>
          <td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" disabled name="chk"></td>
          <td width="43%"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Principal Name" id="txt8">
           <TD>Director or Manager</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
           <td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" disabled name="chk"></td>
           <td width="43%"><input type="text" placeholder="Principal Name" id="txt8">
            <TD>President</TD>
       </TR>
       <TR>
            <td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" disabled name="chk"></td>
            <td width="43%"><input type="text" placeholder="Principal Name" id="txt8">
            <TD>Treasurer</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
             <td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" disabled name="chk"></td>
             <td width="43%"><input type="text" placeholder="Principal Name" id="txt8">
             <TD>Secretary</TD>
        </TR>
 </TABLE>
 <table id="dataTable" border="1">
        <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>
                  <td width="43%"><input type="text" placeholder="New Principal Name" id="txt8"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="New Principal Title" id="txt9"></td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: add a name value to the input field and use that name in `$_POST['']`

Comment: All form fields need a name attribute then you access those values in php either in $_POST[] or $_GET[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First an id is unique. Here you have a lot of `id="txt8"` . Replace them by `class="txt8"` rather.

Then, if you want to get the add input value with $_POST, do that :

```
<td width="43%"><input type="text" placeholder="New Principal Name" class="txt8" name="add"></td>
```

You simply get the value of `$ _POST['add']` in your PHP code.